# Composite class mapping in fluent nhibernate causing problems with updating and primary key

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have 3 tables called Dish, Ingredient and DishIngredient.

**Dish**
Id
Name

**Ingredient**
Id
Name

**DishIngredient**
Id
DishId
IngredientId
Amount

Dish ingredients links the ingredient and the dish, and adds extra details such as amount.

```
    public DishMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Title);
        HasMany(x => x.Ingredients).Fetch.Join().Cascade.All();
    }

    public IngredientMap()
    {
        Table("DishIngredient");
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Amount);

        Join("Ingredient", m =>
        {
            m.Map(x => x.Name);
            m.KeyColumn("Id");
        });
    }
```

This works for getting values out of the database, but when it comes to trying to save or update I get the message:

"NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException : could not insert: 
 [SQL: INSERT INTO Ingredient (Name, Id) VALUES (?, ?)]
  ----> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Ingredient' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF."

So it looks like nhibernate is trying to insert a value into the id column of the Ingredient column, which is an auto-incremented primary key....so obviously it fails.

Can anyone help me out with this one?

Answer (score 0):

Okay....that was a moment of stupidity.... it's not ideal but I don't see another way around it.  I have a mapping class for each table, and Ingredient.Name is now an object - so instead of using Ingredient.Name to get the value, I used Ingredient.Name.Value.  Not ideal but seems to work.